# Extracting ICS Android Calendar as Stand Alone App

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have been asked to blend our company specific events into the existing Android calendar.  Our events have four fields I don't find with the standard CalendarContract.Events class. A boolean "approved" field, an integer "linked" to a resource, and two dateTime fields indicating.

The first step seems to be to extract the existing ICS calendar into a compileable stand alone application.  I have downloaded the android.calendar package from github, but it won't compile in Eclipse.  It appears to be missing certain imports: com.android.common, com.android.commoncalendar, and com.android.ex.

I have searched stackOverflow for help extracting a stand-alone version of android standard apps, but have mostly seen people respond that it is not possible.  I know it is possible because it has been done.  You can find it here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.calendar

I have emailed the developer to see if he would share his source code or at least describe the steps he took to get the package to compile as a stand alone application, but he has not responded.

Can anyone help me with how to fix the missing imports, or better yet point me to a resource that describes step-by-step how I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be in any kind of hurry to rebuild one of the standard apps.  That sounds like a recipe for pain.  Instead, I suggest you make use of the Calendar content provider that is already present, and create another set of tables that indexes by the Calendar CP but adds the rows you are missing.  You could then make a custom cursor that blends these two sources together, or maybe make another content provider to wrap them and keep the cursor simple.

Comment: The problem is that I don't just need the data from the Calendar provider.  I don't want to recreate a calendar program from scratch in order to display our data along with existing calendar data.  For example, the Agenda view has adapters with headers/footers, knows how to add items into the future, handles the color chips for the various calendars you may have loaded, brings up CRUD dialog windows.

Comment: SORRY -- Please disregard comment above.  Accidentally posted before I was finished.  Here is what my question is:

Comment: I must say I don't quite understand your suggestion.  The goal is to avoid recreating an entire calendar UI to display our data.  For example, the existing Agenda Activity and related Adapters have header/footers, manage color chips of calendars, provide full CRUD capabilities for existing calendars, etc.  If I create my own content provider that blends our data with normal data, how do I get our data in the UI without modifying the existing Calendar Activities and Adapters?

Comment: That is a fair question.  I don't have an easy answer.  I'll ask my colleagues what they think.

Comment: Any thoughts from your colleagues?  I know that a central tenant of the Android Open Project is to create building blocks developers can improve on to create better content and use on Android.  The Calendar program is one of the most sophisticated built-in applications on the Android platform.  I can't be the only one who would like to build upon that platform to expand Android's capabilities in new directions.  Is there not some way to extract the source code and build upon it without recreating what is clearly hundreds (if not thousands) of man/hours?

Comment: Everybody agreed that mashing up the content provider together with data of your own was a good way to access the data.  Nobody knew of a way to alter the display of the calendar without modifying the app source code.

Comment: I guess that puts me back to square one: how to extract a compileable project from the calendar source code so we can begin expanding the capabilities without rewriting the UI from scratch. It has apparently been done once, no reason it can't be done again. Of course if anyone has any tips to share, I'm all ears ;)